# Making a Boolean trying to print out uppercase letters

Tags: c++, boolean, uppercase

The objective is to make it so that all uppercase letters are printed out in a string, however, I must keep the bool function and use it within my code. I have resolved some issues from the past but ran up with a issue that is preventing me from fixing it. Test cases are "HEllO" -> "HEO" "my" -> "" "NAME" -> "NAME" "Is" -> "I" "AnDeRsON" -> "ADRON".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

  bool isUpperCase(char ch){
    if(ch >= 'A' and ch <= 'Z'){
      return true;
        }
        return false;
        }

int main() {

  string a = "";
  cin >> a;
  string c = "";
  
  for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {
      if (isUpperCase(a[i])) i++;
        {
          c += a[i];
        }

    }
  cout << c << endl;
}
```

Now whenever I do a case like "CHADnigeria" it turns it into "HDnigeria" even though I want it to say "CHAD". It also removes the capitals which I do not want and it should be removing the lowercases. "DancingInTheSky" turns into "ancingnheky" which should be "DITS". Reminder that the bool function must not be changed though.

Comment: `if (isUpperCase(a[i])) i++;` what is happening here? Remove the `i++`, right?

Comment: ^^^^ lose the trailing `i++;` from that line, note: that includes the semicolon.

Comment: Related, btw, you also don't need a temp string for this. Just enumerate the string `a` with an iterator and if the current character is upper case dump it (the character) to `std::cout`.

Comment: @WhozCraig removing i++ fixed it, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to spoil your hard work, but look at `std::isupper`.  No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your program so that it works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isUpperCase(char ch){
    if(ch >= 'A' and ch <= 'Z'){
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {

    string a = "";
    cin >> a;
    string c = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {       
            if (isUpperCase(a[i]))
            {
                    c += a[i];
            }

    }
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

What was your mistake: You put `i++` after the `if` statement, which caused the weird output.

I hope I could help a little bit

Comment: Someone did fix it in the comments but I appreciate it, it will definitely help someone in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a good programming praxis to write `return condition;` instead of `if (condition) return true; else return false;`. I would write your isUpperCase function just as:

```
bool isUpperCase(char ch) {
    return (ch >= 'A' and ch <= 'Z');
}
```

The mistake you are looking for is in the main function, there is a `i++` which is causing trouble. You wrote:

```
if (isUpperCase(a[i])) i++;
    {
      c += a[i];
    }
```

And the compiler understands it as:

```
if (isUpperCase(a[i])) {
    i++;
}
c += a[i];
```

Also, when you add a single character into a string in C++ i recommend you to use the `push_back()` method instead of the `+` operator. So `c += a[i];` would be `c.push_back(a[i]);`. Both work fine, but `push_back()` is generally more efficient.